# Including number (#) symbol on a quote

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I am having trouble when trying to display the `#` symbol on the start of a quote<sup>1</sup>, as if I do it appears as a header instead, like:

```
> #this
```

> ## this

The only way I could think to partially get it right was to backtick the hash symbol:

```
> `#`Some
```

> `#`Some

**Is there any way I can include a `#` symbol at the start of a quote besides using backticks?** The mixing of colors seems strange when using so, and a bit irruptive to the reader. I already checked [Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) as well as this other [formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) page, but couldn't find a way.

---

<sup>1</sup>In case you were wondering, this happened to me as I needed to quote some text, that included a Python comment in one of its lines.

Comment: Interestingly, now that I am on the App, the backtick bypass looks the same here as the solutions in the answers... I guess because they both have a gray background, while on web the quotes are pale yellow (on Meta SE at least)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to escape the # with a backslash, like this:

```
> \#test
```

which parses as:

> #test

BTW, note that you can also have a code block inside a quote:

```
>     #like this
```

which parses as:

> ```
> #like this
> ```

Comment: Good, this manages to display the number symbol as desired :) thanks

Comment: hehe, found another way to display it. I wonder which is preferred over the other?

Comment: Whichever you find easiest to type, I'd say.

Comment: In that case, I think that "\" is faster to type than the Entity :-) but, what I meant is that if there are preference to, say, not use Entities on posts when possible or something like that... but surely the slash is more accessible.

Answer (score 4):

Well, further testing out and playing with the quotes I managed to obtain an alternative solution to the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307992/332286) already provided, by using [HTML Entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```
> &num;test
```

Which parses as:

> #test

Answer (score 2):

The other options are better, but because `#` has ASCII character code 35 (in hexadecimal: 23), the following options work as well:

```
> &#35;test

> &#x23;test
```

> #test
>
> #test

There's a slight irony here in the fact that you're using a # again, but in a different way.

Comment: Interesting variation of the Entities use, and yes, quite ironic to see the number symbol there :) thanks